# Replacing existing record in MySQL or create new record without having Primary keys or Unique fields

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP and I need to insert a new record in a MySQL DB or if it exists simply update it. I read several answers where they propose to use `REPLACE` or `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, however if I well understood, these two option imply the use of unique fields or primary keys (that are unique). In my case the MySQL table has values similar to this:

```
Timestamp            | Query1   | Query2   | Result
-------------------------------------------------------- 
2012-10-13 08:15:27  | American | Men      | here result

2012-10-13 08:15:23  | American | Men      | result2

2012-10-13 08:15:27  | American | Women    | other result

2012-10-13 08:15:27  | German   | Men      | here result
```

Therefore I cannot have primary keys or univoque fields since "query1", "query2" and "Result" can have the same values (e.g. I can have several records with more fields containing "American" (query1) and "Men" (query2) and different results.

At the moment in PHP I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO results (Timestamp, Query1, Query2, Result) VALUES ('$current_timestamp', '$nationality', '$gender', '')
```

Which just append all the records and create a huge DB. But what I want to achieve is adding a new record just if the entire combination query1&query2&result doesn't exist. Otherwise I just want to update the "timestamp" field.

For instance if my PHP script produces the following data:

```
Timestamp            | Query1   | Query2   | Result
2012-10-13 08:15:23  | American | Men      | result2
```

and the database already contains this exact combination of "American"&"Men"&"result2" then just the field "timestamp" is updated. Otherwise, if the combination is different (e.g. "American" "Men" "result3) a new record is added to the table.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even absent a single `PRIMARY KEY` column like a typical `AUTO_INCREMENT` integer, if those three columns are meant to be a unique combination you ought to define them as a composite key .  This will not only preserve uniqueness but also enforce indexing on them as a unit.

```
CREATE TABLE results (
  `Timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `Query1` VARCHAR() NOT NULL,
  `Query2` VARCHAR() NOT NULL,
  `Result` VARCHAR() NOT NULL,
  /* Composite key across three columns */
  PRIMARY KEY (`Query1`,`Query2`,`Result`)
);
```

You may then use [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) when inserting to abort insertion on key violations and update the timestamp instead.

```
INSERT INTO results (
   Timestamp, 
   Query1, 
   Query2, 
   Result
) VALUES (
   '$current_timestamp', /* see note below about NOW() */
   '$nationality', 
   '$gender',
   ''
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Timestamp` = '$current_timestamp';
```

Note: We assume the PHP variables have been properly escaped already.

Note 2: If the value of `$current_timestamp` is indeed the current timestamp and not some stored value, I recommend using MySQL's `NOW()` function rather than pass in a PHP variable.

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Timestamp` = NOW()
```

Same goes for the `$current_timestamp` in the `VALUES()` list...

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional insert like this one:

```
INSERT INTO results (Timestamp, Query1, Query2, Result) 
SELECT '$current_timestamp', '$nationality', '$gender', '$result'
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM results
                         WHERE Query1 = '$nationality' 
                           AND Query2 = '$gender'
                           AND Result = '$result')
```

`dual` is a special one-column table originally introduced in Oracle

source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'WHERE NOT EXISTS' clause, like that:

```
INSERT INTO results (Timestamp, Query1, Query2, Result)
SELECT '$current_timestamp', '$nationality', '$gender', '$result'
FROM Dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
    FROM results 
    WHERE Query1 = '$nationality' 
    AND Query2 = '$gender'
    AND Result = '$result'
  )
```

Here Dual is a stub/fake table that you can use in mysql only to make the query syntaxically correct.

Comment: -1, you have syntax error on the 2nd line and how does your answer differ from mine?

Comment: I was just trying to help, and yes, we came to the same solution because it's the most obvious one. Now, if it makes your day to downvote me, good for you, I'm fine with that.